# String not recognised in intent.putExtra Unexpected tokens error

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6q3u.png)

fun createBirthdayCard(view: View) {

```
     val name = nameInput.editableText.toString()

     val intent = Intent(this, BirthdayGreeting::class.java)
        intent.putExtra(name:"name", name)
     startActivity(intent)
 }
```

}

Comment: Typo. Remove the `name:` first thing inside the `putExtra()` call. You're apparently copying code from an image/video of an IDE with parameter hints enabled. Those hints aren't part of the code; the IDE simply shows them as reminders as you type.

Answer (score 0):

remove name: you don't need to mention it . just write like this

```
   intent.putExtra("name", name)
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `name:` from putExtra
i.e

```
val intent = Intent(this, BirthdayGreeting::class.java)
intent.putExtra("name", name)
startActivity(intent)
```